# Don't understand overlapping between clusters, kmeans

Tags: scikit-learn, data-science, cluster-analysis, k-means, iris-dataset

how come there are overlaps in my clusters ? Is it because sklearn.KMeans finish the iterations too soon ? graph: [kmeans cluster sepal iris flower](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCQRX.png)
some clarifications:

- the data is 4D, values are standardized (@OmG pointed the answer to my question)
- I've uploaded 3 files here : [github repository](https://github.com/Liam-Noah/kmeans_overlap)

```
    - code.py  - minimum for this question
    - code_notebook.ipynb same as code.py + other functions
    - iris-dataset.csv : the dataset
```

because the example I was working on, always plotted only the first 2 columns, I thought I was running the clustering on only those two variables. Thanks for pointing the answer to the question !

Comment: Is data 2D? Or did you reduce the dimension for the visualization?

Comment: Please add your code and data (or link to data if data is too huge)

Comment: I think you are confusing graphically overlap with actual cluster overlap, they should only ever belong to one cluster in a traditional kmeans, they just look like they overlap when you graph them that way. @OmG asked an excellent question. Did you reduce dimensions to graph it?

Comment: @Abhi25t I added the code, and dataset to github.

Comment: @OmG I thought a bit better and realized that I was working on 4D data, that explains the overlapping in 2D plotting ... thanks for drawing the attention on this point!

Comment: @DejaVuSansMono data is actually 4D which explains the 2D overlap